# How to fix TypeError "unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'" when comparing values for two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I want to count the number of instances (rows) in a dataframe satisfying two conditions.

The first one being if the value in the column `Long / Short` is equal to `Long`.
And the second one being if the value in the column `Gap Size` is greater than 100.

I suppose that before I can count the number of instances (rows) satisfying both condition then I could simply "filter out" the rows not satisfying both and then use either `len` or `count` (I do not know which is better?).

I am able to check for each of the conditions at a time and use either `len` or `count` to find the number of rows for each condition - but not both simultaneously.

My original dataframe (named `tradelog_df` looks something like this (I have more columns but they are not needed for the conditions):

```
0      27.5        Short
1      29.0        Long
2      20.8        Short
3      52.2        Long
4       5.3        Short
[...]
220     -29.3         Long
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
long_trades = tradelog_df[abs(tradelog_df["Gap Size"]).gt(100) & tradelog_df["Long / Short"] == "Long"].count()
```

I receive the following error when trying to run the code:

```
C:\Users\kenno\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:1167: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kenno\Desktop\DAX_GAP\dax_datamanager.py", line 130, in <module>
    long_trades = tradelog_df[abs(tradelog_df["Gap Size"]).gt(100) & tradelog_df["Long / Short"] == "Long"].count()
  File "C:\Users\kenno\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1283, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)
  File "C:\Users\kenno\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1169, in na_op
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Comment: Put brackets around your comparison: `(tradelog_df["Long / Short"] == "Long")`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be a very simple fix!